# Write a Closed Expression in which we can calculate with Computer the probability of counting ...

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Number of meters between $2$ Ant Coloneys in a road Is Exponential random variable with Variance $25 ~(meter)^2$.

in $1$ **KiloMeters** we counted $100$ Coloneys . Write a Closed Expression in which we can calculate with Computer the probability of counting **at least** $150$ **Aditional** colones in that kilometer.

You are forbidden to put the sign $\infty$ in your Final answer.

**Answer Attempt :**

First Let N be random Vairable with $N$~$Poison$ $(\lambda = \frac{1}{\lambda_{exp}} = 200)$
the number of colonies per **kilometer**.

$P(N) = \frac{e^{-200}~200^n}{n!}$

$P(100+150\leq N|100<N) = \frac{P(250\leq N)}{P(100<N)} = 
\frac{1- \int_0^{250}{\frac{e^{-200}~200^n}{n!}dn}}{1- \int_0^{100}{\frac{e^{-200}~200^n}{n!}dn}}$

First is this the correct answer

second how can one continue to get closed expression

third why did they write the last sentence and include computer information

thanks.

Comment: It should be sum since it’s discrete but the idea is the same

Comment: I don´t understand the exercise. We already have counted 100 colonies **in that  kilometer**. How can we count at least 150 additional colonies **in that kilometer**?

Comment: We didn’t finish counting we know 100% that till now we counted 100 . What is the probability that we count additional 150 at least from now on .

Comment: So I am sure it’s conditional probability because we are using what we know from past or till the current state

Comment: @callculus ....

Comment: just FYI - the plural of "colony" is "colonies".

Comment: I am not taking English lessons who cares it’s math the language of math

Comment: For me it is still not clear. So we count 100 colonies in 400m for instance? And then it is asked for the probability of counting at least 150 additional colonies in that kilometer? Or do we count that kilometer twice? One time we count 100 colonies and then it is asked for the probability that we count at least 250 colonies at the second time?

Comment: @callculus no it’s a road we count it once and only one time . As i said we counted till now 100 in this road and now we continue counting in the same road . What is the probability that we count at least 150 additional colonies .